# Failure when changing color in Adobe Illustrator CS6 turn a single object to double overlaping objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, illustrator-effects, eyedropper

I tried to change some text color using eyedropper tool from another object but it seemed to fail. The color didn't change, or on other occasions it turns to different color that i don't pick up. When i check the apparance panel/color info, it has changed to the color that i've picked up, eventhough the actual object is not. But when i look closely it looks like the color i've picked appears as a very thin outline, but there's no color in the appearance panel for the stroke.

I'm trying whatever i can to fix this, at some point i expanded my text and ungroup it. It appears that when i change the color, my object turns to two overlapping objects, and the color that i choose only appear in the bottom object which is covered by the upper object that retain the old color.

Anyone know how to fix this? Eyedropper's setting still the same, and the problem sometimes happen when i try to change the color manually. It started to happens several days ago, so i've restarted the software and my pc pretty often.
I've attached some screenshots to make it clearer.

[image: first object before i change the color]

[image: i've change the text's color using eyedropper on the green circle. as you can see the text still black but the appearance panel says it's green. instead i got a very thin green outline]

[image: i've expanded the text and delete some nodes, it shows that there is two object overlapped, and the green one laid behind]

Comment: Please expand the appearance panel so we can see all of the applied effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live text objects do not fill/stroke the same as standard objects within Illustrator.

The `Characters` item in the **Appearance Panel** contains a fill and stroke for the *live* text. If you **double-click** the `Characters` item in the Appearance Panel, you'll see the *actual* fill and stroke of the text. You can then remove either one or both as necessary.

[image]

The best method of changing color for *live* text is to use the **Color Panel** (Window > Color) combined with perhaps the **Swatches Panel** (Window > Swatches).

In many instanced the Eyedropper tool works in an unexpected manner on live text. Text is simply not the same as a standard vector object.

See here for more information: [Illustrator: Text shown not to have a fill has a fill](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/118467/illustrator-text-shown-not-to-have-a-fill-has-a-fill)

Comment: thank you for the explanation and the suggestion! just realize I have the problem on grouped vector object as well, now I need to change my workflow :/ I've been using ai for over 2 years and I don't think eyedropper tool ever did that to my text/object before, was it a bug? does it still works that way in adobe illustrator cc?